# Basic Alegbra simplification

Tags: linear-algebra

```
the sum of x+1 and the reciprocal of x-1 is....???
```

The answer should be $x^2/(x-1)$. But how this is possible, can anyone explain it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you try adding these?  Can you put it down in the question?

Answer (score 3):

$$x+1+\frac{1}{x-1}=\frac{(x+1)(x-1)+1}{x-1}=\frac{x^2-1+1}{x-1}=\frac{x^2}{x-1}$$